# jQuery smooth expend/collapse accordian/carousel

Tags: jquery, accordion, carousel

With the help of stack overflow before, I got an answer on how to make the carousel/accordian here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UdUus/117/

smoothly open/close without the whole thing moving. The key was the little used step property.

However, I am trying to work out how I can tweak this script so that onload, all items are the same width, and then expand/contract as neccessary on hover, and then collapses back to its original state on mouseleave.

I have tried but to no avail. Anyone any ideas?

A.

Comment: Hi Neurofluxation... Ive ticked a few more, but some have never got a 'correct' answer so I havent ticked them :) Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: jsfiddle link is broken and your question become unanswerable

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="promo">
        <ul>
            <li class="promo1">d</li>
            <li class="promo2">d</li>
            <li class="promo3">d</li>
            <li class="promo4">d</li>
            <li class="promo5">d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#promo { width:404x; height:200px; overflow:hidden; }
#promo ul { width:105%; }
#promo li { float:left; height:200px; margin-right:1px; width:50px; }
#promo .promo1 { background:red;}
#promo .promo2 { background:green; }
#promo .promo3 { background:red; }
#promo .promo4 { background:green; }
#promo .promo5 { background:red; margin-right:0px; }
```

JS:

```
var panels = $('#promo li');

panels.hoverIntent(

function() {
    if (!$(this).is('.expanded')) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: 200
        }, {
            step: function(width, ani) {
                var w = Math.floor(width);
                $('.expanded').css('width', (250 - w) + 'px');
                $(ani.elem).css('width', (200 - w) + 'px');
            },
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() {
                panels.removeClass('expanded');
                $(this).addClass('expanded');
            }
        });
    }
}, function() {});

$("#promo").hover(function() {}, function() {

    $("li.expanded", this).animate({
        width: 50,
        duration: 500
    }).removeClass("expanded");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/UdUus/252/)

Comment: Just tested it on my Firefox 3.6.13 and it worked fine. Though I am using Ubuntu and not Windows.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Thor I apologise for this and will try getting the code into the answer as quickly as I can.